# How to create variable names dynamicaly in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am quite new new to AngularJs.  In my controller i have a `$rootScope` variables which i want to assign a value dynamically depending on conditions.
Following is my controller code:

```
controller(){

$rootScope.tab1;
$rootScope.tab2;
$rootScope.tab3;
$rootScope.tab3;
$rootScope.tab4;

$scope.changeVal("tab2");

$scope.changeVal=function(tabname){
    vm.tabs=['tab1','tab2','tab3','tab4','tab5'];
    angular.forEach(vm.tabs, function(val) {
        if(tabname===val)
        {
            //here $rootScope.tab2 value should be changed
            //something like bellow
            $rootScope.{{tabname}}="myValue";
        }
        else{
        $rootScope.$eval(val)="";
        }
    });

}
```

}

I know that , by applying multiple if or switch conditions this can be done. But, finding some optimized solution.
Any help would be appriciated. Thanx in advance.

Comment: The following remarks answer your question, but why use `$rootScope`? Is using a local `$scope`not enough? Try limiting the digest cycle if possible. Another way to store application variables is to use `services` (singleton).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use

```
$rootScope[tabname]="myValue";
```

`$rootScope` is like an `object` in `angular` on which you can add properties and access properties like how you do with `plain old javascript`.

Answer (score 0):

root scope is just another javascript object, so you'd do

```
$rootScope[tabname]="myValue";
```

(That said, it's generally not a great idea to stuff a lot of data directly into `$rootScope`, that's the Angular equivalent of using global variables for everything...)

Comment: i agree with you. Actually this is sample code, i have to use these variables in all over my application, so they are global ones.

Comment: If you need to share data across the application, consider using a service instead of root scope.

Comment: Yes. But for a moment your solution is not working. I think it thinks that expression as array.

Comment: That syntax works for objects too. for example  `var foo = {}; var bar="baz"; foo[bar] = "bat";`  I'm not sure what's going wrong for you, can you be more specific about what happened?  "That's not working" doesn't give much to go on